# How to log Yii2 "Deprecated Warning" without displaying them

Tags: php, logging, yii2

For a change from PHP 8.0 to 8.1, I have a lot of PHP *Deprecated Warnings* displayed. I could simply switch them off, but it would be better to fix them for PHP 8.2, so I try to get a silent logger of these warnings to collect them while my app is running in PHP 8.1. What setting in [Yii 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii) and PHP do I have to prepare? Is this possible?

When I set up PHP for `error_reporting( E_ALL );` then Yii 2 applications shows the error. This is not the "silent" way.

Yii2 configuration: file *main.php*

```
'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
```

How can I just log these PHP Warnings without stopping the code to run?

Comment: Can you add an example of such a warning? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer of @kasoft didn't work for me. I had to create a custom error handler:

`components/CustomErrorHandler.php`:

```php
<?php
namespace app\components;

class CustomErrorHandler extends \yii\web\ErrorHandler {

    public function handleError($code, $message, $file, $line) {
        // Skip showing notices and warning, continue execution (usually you want to configure PHP to log them though)
        if (in_array($code, [E_NOTICE, E_WARNING])) {
            return false;
        }

        // For other errors use default behavior
        parent::handleError($code, $message, $file, $line);
    }

}
```

And configure it in `config/web.php`:

```php
// ...
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    'class' => 'app\components\CustomErrorHandler',
],
// ...
```